# Gerar migration baseado no model (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando gerar uma migration baseado em um model:

```
  [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NomeInstituicao_Fundamental { get; set; }
    public string AnoInicio_Fundamental { get; set; }
    public string AnoFim_Fundamental { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NomeInstituicao_Superior { get; set; }
    public string AnoInicio_Superior { get; set; }
    public string AnoFim_Superior { get; set; }

    public Aluno aluno{ get; set; }
```

Só que depois de executar o comando: *Add-Migration*, é gerado minha migration, porém a função *Up()* vem vazia. Preciso que ela já venha modelado, igual aos atributos definidos no meu model.

```
 public partial class AcademicosMig : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Context:

```
    public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("name=Default")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    public  DbSet<Academicos> Academico_ { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar sua tabela à sua implementação do `DbContext`

```
public class DatabaseEntities : DbContext {
    public virtual DbSet<AcademicosMig> AcademicosMigs{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: O meu ficou assim:   public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context() : base("name=Default")
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<Academicos> academicos { get; set; }

      
    }

E ainda assim continuo sem conseguir gerar a migraiton

Answer (score 0):

Já pensou em utilizar fluent API para fazer o mapeamento do banco acho mais prático, outra coisa verifica o seu construtor e tenta passar  o name do banco assim:

```
public Context() : base("Default")
```